# Upload Active PPT on Sharepoint

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I am trying to upload an active presentation on sharepoint and facing issues with the code. Below is the script. Please help fix:

```
  Sub Saveuploadppt()

        'Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
         Dim filenm As Variant
         Dim month As String
         Dim d As String
         Dim powerpoint As Object
          month = Format(Date - 1, "mmm'yy")
         d = Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy")
         filenm = "Control Dashboard " & month & "MTD_" & d & ".pptx"

         MsgBox filenm
         powerpoint.Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "File path "", 1

  End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to read this and then fix the file name / path in your code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentation-saveas-method-powerpoint

Comment: Thanks Ralph for the suggestion. I found the answer :)
Sub Saveuploadppt()

 'Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim filenm As Variant
 Dim month As String
 Dim d As String
 Dim powerpoint As Object
  month = Format(Date - 1, "mmm'yy")
 d = Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy")
 filenm = "Control Dashboard " & month & "MTD_" & d & ".pptx"
 
 MsgBox filenm
  
Dim ppApp As powerpoint.Application

Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
ppApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "path" & filenm & "", 1

 End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Hello below is the solution:)

```
Sub Saveuploadppt()

'Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application

 Dim filenm As Variant

 Dim month As String

 Dim d As String

 Dim powerpoint As Object

 month = Format(Date - 1, "mmm'yy")

 d = Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy")

 filenm = "Control Dashboard " & month & "MTD_" & d & ".pptx"

 MsgBox filenm

 Dim ppApp As powerpoint.Application

 Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

 PpApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "path" & filenm & "", 1

 End Sub
```